# Kubernetes: Unable to connect to the server: Service Unavailable

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

After reboot of kubernetes master node,  "kubectl" command throwing this error:

```
Unable to connect to the server: Service Unavailable
```

Kindly suggest how to start the service or fix this issue.

```
# kubectl get nodes
Unable to connect to the server: Service Unavailable
#
# kubectl cluster-info

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
Unable to connect to the server: Service Unavailable
#
# echo $KUBECONFIG
/root/.kube/config
#

# kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://192.168.1.1:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
#
```

Comment: Check if kube-apiserver is running. Look at its logs. Try and start or restart it.

Comment: Most likely you do not have apiserver running

Comment: please provide the output of ```docker ps | grep api ``` and ```https://192.168.1.1:6443```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You did not specify which container driver your cluster is using, so I'm going to assume it is `docker`, also assuming you are using linux.*

Most probably you don't have `kube-apiserver` running. You have to start/restart it to solve your issue.

1. Check if docker daemon is running. If not, start/restart it.

   ```text
   $ systemctl status docker
   ```

   ```text
   # systemctl start docker
   ```

   or

   ```text
   # systemctl restart docker
   ```
2. Once docker daemon is running, check if `kube-apiserver` container is running

   ```text
   # docker ps -a
   ```

   look for a container with *COMMAND* `kube-apiserver`. If it's running you are done, if not, restart it

   ```text
   # docker restart <container ID>
   ```

---

To ensure you won't have the same problem in the future, [configure Docker to start on boot](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#configure-docker-to-start-on-boot)

```text
# systemctl enable docker.service
# systemctl enable containerd.service
```

---

If your distribution does not user `systemd` use `service` instead of `systemctl`

```text
# service <service name> status/stop/start/restart
```

In above commands `$` means run as normal user, `#` means run as root.